# Selenium WebDriver for Java Applet based websites

Tags: java, security, applet, selenium-webdriver

I have a website which uses a Java applet. I am trying to automate it using Cucumber & Selenium WebDriver. However, every time I run the website in browser, I get a java security alert (see image), which should be explicitly allowed to proceed further.

Sample image - [Java Security alert image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPTZe.png)

At present, I am unable to proceed beyond this step. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an alert to test.. but what's about driver.switchTo().alert().accept() ?

Comment: Its not the webpage's native element, which I can switch to. Owing to recent Java vulnerabilities, this sort of alert usually comes up on all java based sites. Try [this site](http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp). You might get a [similar alert](http://i.imgur.com/WD5Z3bI.png).